# $item->getQtyBackordered() in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

i can't find the right way to get if a product is backordered.
In magento 1 was

```
$item->getQtyBackordered()
```

In magento 2?

this is my cart.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
?>
<?php
/**
* Shopping cart template
*
* @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart
*/

$check = false;

foreach($block->getItems() as $item) {

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$GP = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
$disp = $GP->getResource()->getAttribute('selezione_disponibilita')->getFrontend()->getValue($GP);

if(strpos($disp, 'disponibile') !== false){

    $check = true;

}

if($item->getQtyBackordered() > 0){
   $check = true;
};   

}

if($check == true){

?>

<div style="display:block; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding: 20px; margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">
    <?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('avviso_spedizione')->toHtml();
    ?> 
</div>

<?php

}

if ($block->getItemsCount()) {
echo $block->getChildHtml('with-items');
} else {
echo $block->getChildHtml('no-items');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes in Magento2 it is the same [`getQtyBackordered()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php#L1358) you can find it Implementations from `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item`

```
     /**
     * Returns qty_backordered
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function getQtyBackordered()
    {
        return $this->getData(OrderItemInterface::QTY_BACKORDERED);
    }
```

**EDIT**

You can get it by `$item->getBackorders()` thanks to [goplastic](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/36019/goplastic). My answer will work after order is placed (I mean `Item` object should be `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item` )

Comment: i've edited my question with the code of my cart.phtml. getQtyBackordered() gives me null, can you check what i am doing wrong? thank you

Comment: i found that getBackorders() works!

Comment: I updated my answer so you can accept the answer or you can add your new answer @goplastic otherwise question will be open forever :)